# Trying to get columns while reading multiple csv files. Only getting first two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am reading all csv files in a folder (approx. 90 files). Each file has around 85 columns and I'm just interested in 2, so I'm trying to copy just these in my df. But the df I'm getting is only showing the first two columns.

The csv files look like this: [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po6tW.png)

My code:

```
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join("C:/User/Documents/Auswertung/2/Vent_2022/*.csv"))
frames = [pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', low_memory=False, usecols = ['LOCALTIME', 'Flow_filter'], names = ['LOCALTIME', 'Flow_filter']) for file in csv_files]
df_vent = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index = True)
df_vent.drop([0,1,2], axis=0, inplace=True)

display(df_vent)
```

What I'm trying to get:

| LOCALTIME | Flow_filter |
| --- | --- |
| 01.07.2022 00:01:00 | 69 |
| 24.07.2022 22:46:00 | 167 |
| 09.08.2022 15:14:00 | 38 |
| 06.09.2022 18:45:00 | 51 |

What I'm getting:

| LOCALTIME | Flow_filter |
| --- | --- |
| 01.07.2022 00:01:00 | 01.07.2022 00:01:00 |
| 24.07.2022 22:46:00 | 24.07.2022 22:46:00 |
| 09.08.2022 15:14:00 | 09.08.2022 15:14:00 |
| 06.09.2022 18:45:00 | 06.09.2022 18:45:00 |

Does someone know why this is happening and how I can correct it? Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

I followed a suggestion of removing

> names = ['LOCALTIME', 'Flow_filter']

but know the df's first column is a mixture of column 1 and 3. Something like this:

| LOCALTIME | Flow_filter |
| --- | --- |
| 01.07.2022 00:01:00 | 69 |
| 24.07.2022 22:46:00 | 167 |
| 3 | 38 |
| 3 | 51 |

Here's a picture: [odd df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK5gv.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the `names = ['LOCALTIME', 'Flow_filter']` option to `pd.read_csv`, you are actually overriding the header row in the file, and thus saying that those are the names of the first two columns. Then you say pick those two columns, therefore the first two.

Since your file has a header row, simply removing that option will let `pd.read_csv` read the column names for you, and then `usecols = ...` should work as you expect.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! It semi worked... The second column looks good but the first column is now a mixture of column 1 and 3.

Comment: That's rather odd. Is there something weird going on with your input file?

Comment: I just checked the files and didn't find anything weird. The first column on all files is only Timestamp.

Comment: The number of total columns in each file is not the same. Could this be a cause for my problem? Although the columns I want exist in all files.

Comment: Is it possible that the file that has those records with the `3` has the columns indirectly labeled?